# ExpressJS detect connections from kubernetes services

Tags: express, nginx, kubernetes

I have a kubernetes cluster with a NodeJS micro-service. The micro-service has an endpoint that is accessible from inside the cluster as well as outside of the cluster through an nginx reverse proxy.

I would like to be able to detect inside this endpoint whether the incoming request comes from inside or outside the cluster.

Since I would like the deployment of this NodeJS app to be flawless no matter which kubernetes platform I deploy it, I don't want to use static IP check. I have few ideas but don't know which approach is the best and how to implement it.

1. Detect the local address and check if it's in the same IP prefix (not sure if nginx will return it's own IP so that might not work)
2. Detect if it comes from nginx - not sure if there is a default header that can't be removed by the client or anything that can be detected from ExpressJS
3. Detect somehow if it comes from a service inside the cluster (maybe there is a header or something that would indicate me that it's part of the same cluster)

I would like to know which idea (maybe not in this list) to pick and how I implement it in ExpressJS.